# index out of bound exception in java when accessing index of list

Tags: java, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a list and when I try to access the index of that list it gives index out of bound exception and when I print the value of that index in another method ,Its showing the result I can't understand when value is there at that particular index why **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0** is thrown.

My java code is-

```
public  List<Vacc_vs6> refarray_vac1(String fdate,String ldate) throws SQLException, ParseException {

            st_jsp.clear();


           try
                {  
                  con = getConnection();
                  stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);


                         String vs1= "sql query";

                  stmt.executeQuery(vs1);
                   rs = stmt.getResultSet();

                   while (rs.next()) {
                       Vacc_vs6 ref = new Vacc_vs6();

                          ref.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));
                          ref.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));
                          ref.setBeam_energy(rs.getString(3));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag1_rb(rs.getString(4));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag2_rb(rs.getString(5));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag3_rb(rs.getString(6));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag4_rb(rs.getString(7));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag5_rb(rs.getString(8));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag6_rb(rs.getString(9));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag7_rb(rs.getString(10));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag8_rb(rs.getString(11));
                          ref.setst4_vs6_bag9_rb(rs.getString(12));
                      st_jsp.add(ref);

                    }

                }
           catch( Exception e )
                    {
            System.out.println("\nException in refarray_vac1 "+e);
                    }
           List<Vacc_vs6> new_list=new ArrayList<Vacc_vs6>();
            double is = 9.5;
             double js = 10.5;
             int no=0;
        for(no=0;no<=10;no++)
            {
                String i= st_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current();//**Showing exception here**
                double im = Double.parseDouble(i) ;
                if(im>is && im<js) 
                 {
                    new_list.addAll(st_jsp);
                 }
                else
                {
                    new_list.addAll(st_jsp);
                }
                 is +=10;js +=10; 

                }

           return st_jsp;
          }
```

When I define another method

```
public String get_Array()
{  

 List<Vacc_vs6> new_list=new ArrayList<Vacc_vs6>();
String i= st_jsp.get(0).getBeam_current();

System.out.println("noeee"+i);
return i;
}
```

Then value is being printed at 0 index.**Then Why exception is thrown when i run the above method??**

Edit-1

I did corrected it with **st_jsp.size()**.But according to `if(im>is && im<js)` loop if the value at first index is not between given number then it should go to else and 0 should be added at that partiular position.But its not happening .
Now **IndexOutOfBoundsException** exception is not occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping till 10 without knowing how many st_jsp list

replace you for loop with

```
     for(no=0;no<st_jsp.size();no++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making an assumption that `st_jsp` would contain at least 11 elements :

```
    for (no=0;no<=10;no++) {
        String i= st_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current();
```

Based on the exception you got, it contains 0 elements.

A safer loop would be

```
    for (no=0;no<st_jsp.size();no++) {
        String i= st_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current();
```

Comment: @tiddirastogi I read your edit. `if(im>is && im<js)` will never be reached if `st_jsp.size()` is 0, since the for loop won't be entered at all.